# .NET Core Azure Function deployment fails

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I try to set up a release pipeline for my Azure function. It's a `v2 (.NET Core)` project. Locally it works just fine, so I'd like to deploy it to Azure via DevOps.

I created the build pipeline with the standard steps (`dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`, etc.). It goes through fine and creates the artifact.

But I struggle to set up correctly the deployment. The pipeline has three tasks:

1. Stop Azure App Service
2. Deploy Azure App Service (I selected the *Subscription*, `Function App` as *App type* and the target *App service*).
3. Start Azure App Service

The second step fails, and I get the following error message:

> Failed to deploy web package to App Service.

If I click on the more detailed log, I get this:

> 2019-02-04T02:25:43.4893738Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service. 
>   2019-02-04T02:25:43.4905786Z ##[error]Error: (2/4/2019 2:25:42 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.

The content of `azure-ci.yaml`:

```
resources:
- repo: self
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore

    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test

    projects: '$(Parameters.TestProjects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish

    publishWebProjects: false

    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

My questions are:

- What do I miss for the deployment task?
- Could it be something with the build pipeline? So the build artifact is "not in the right format", currently it's a ZIP file
- Do I need the separate stop / start tasks or they are included in the deployment already?

Comment: It would be great if you can post your yaml file for the build pipeline

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican I updated the description, it's there

Comment: You may need to change the "PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" to "PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Release" in your last step.

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican I tried, but it doesn't help, the build fails as `Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\1\a\Release`

Comment: Can you try disabling the stop / start steps?

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican Sure. Sadly it makes no difference, I got the same error message

Comment: Does Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects value contain multiple projects?

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican no, it's the .csproj file of the Azure Function project

Comment: @Szeki Did you use the default Azure App Service Deploy v4.* in release pipeline?

Comment: @JerryLiu I used the default task, but the version was only 3.* at the time of creation

Comment: @JerryLiu indeed, with the v4.* it does work fine, if you wish, just add it as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the latest 4.x Azure App Service Deploy task. It uses [Run From Package](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84) by default, which enforces the atomicity of project deployed on Azure and could avoid many troubles.